# require typescript and multiple implementations

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I'm using a typescript. I have to import Axios lib with "require" but I'm getting an any type as the result

```js
const axios = require('axios').Axios;
const response = await axios.get(url);
```

Error: "**Unsafe call of any typed value**". axios is an "any type" state. require('axios') is in "multiple implementations" state. Why it's not typed? Everything works whren I'm using "import":

```js
import Axios from 'Axios';
```

Variants I tried and got fail:

```js
const axios = require('axios').Axios;
const response = await axios.get(url);

const axios = require('axios');
const response = await axios.get(url);

const axios = require('axios').get;
const response = await get(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const response = await axios.get(url);
```

Comment: It's also not working

Comment: so I think the problem must be in the await outside an async function

try to wrap it in a (async () => { your await })()

Comment: This code inside async function, so everything fine with it. Typescript gives an error that axios is an any type

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.